# html5sortable - understanding "ghost" element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5sortable

I am using the currently-maintained version of html5sortable, found here: https://github.com/voidberg/html5sortable

If I load up the plain (non-Angular) HTML sample page included, I see two different behaviours for "ghosts" that are attached to the cursor during drag operations:

In the very first list, when you drag an item in Chrome, the ghost fades to nothing (gradient from original to transparency) around the edges.

In the grid list, which is initialized with the same options, the ghost is just a slightly transparent clone of the original. In other words it doesn't fade as a "gradient", the whole element is just faded out a bit.

I can't figure out how to intentionally get this second behaviour. In my application, I keep getting the first.

I couldn't discern from the code how to just append a ghost to the DOM. Is it being created at the browser API level? (vs. jQuery UI where it is literally a new element appended to the document). I did discover a class for general styling purposes; however, even when this style does not include a "fade to transparent edges" effect, there is one in place.

Normally I'd be happy just writing it off to the HTML5 implementation just "doing it" for me but I can see examples in the same browser on the same page with the same JS initialization (another example is the connected list) in which that fade doesn't happen. I must be missing something glaringly obvious!

FWIW, my markup looks something like this:

```
<ul id="available" class="source connected">              
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
</ul>
<ul id="active" class="target connected">              
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
</ul>
```

and my initialization looks like this:

```
$(".source, .target").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connected",
});
```

I have some styles but none of them include gradients or even transparency for that matter. I have looked at the html5sortable source code and see references to neither transparency nor gradients.

--

Alternatively, if I could figure out how to append a sample "ghost" to the DOM, that would be great... but inspecting the DOM on drag leads me to believe that it's at the browser implementation level rather than the DOM level anyhow...?

Comment: On other systems and browsers (initially tested on Chrome 41 and Fx 37 for Windows 8) the inconsistency is not always there. Some environments always show the desired "uniform reduction in opactity" expected behaviour. The question still remains: why? Why 2 different behaviours (the expected and the unexpected gradient to transparency) on the exact same page? If I could discover the browser quirk, I could still possibly implement a fix. A combination of display, overflow, and other CSS values? Not sure.